The proper way to limit framerate when recording screen on macOS
macOS 14.5, FFmpeg 7.0.1. To record the screen, if I use the code from Wiki, that is,
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i 1 output.mp4

the frame rate seems to be so high that when I press q to stop recording, the following message persists until my MacBook Pro starts to noise by its cooler: "[q] command received. Exiting."
My current solution is to add -r after -i:
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i 1 -r 24 output.mp4

But I heard that a more correct solution is to replace -r with -framerate and to put it before instead of after -i:

ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 24 -i 1 output.mp4

Note that I used -framerate as an input option instead of -r 24 as an output option, so I'm telling avfoundation to record at 24fps instead of recording at the default fps and then forcing FFmpeg to drop or duplicate frames to give you the desired 24.

This doesn't work for me currently, and appears to be the same as I don't use -r at all.
And so, what is the proper way to fix the "too high framerate" issue when recording the screen on macOS? Do we need -r or instead -framerate, and where to put it, before or after -i?
Just in case, here is the log of ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i 1 output.mp4 -v verbose:
https://github.com/jsx97/test/blob/main/ffmpeg.log

From the log, it is apparent that initially not enough frames are received for ffmpeg to detect input framerate.
That's ok, you can just use pass through input frames without any adjustment.
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i 1 -fps_mode passthrough output.mp4


Many thanks, Gyan. "You can just use pass through input frames without any adjustment." - You mean this is the best possible solution, though there are more of them?

And could you explain the difference between your and my solutions, that is, between using -r 24 and -fps_mode passthrough?

Other solution would be to set a manual framerate like you did, but that would generally result in duplicating or dropping input frames.
